# What is the correct value of ODBCDM_Home for unixodbc on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, unixodbc, oracleclient

I installed `unixodbc` and `unixodbc-dev` through `apt-get`. I then installed oracle instantclient (both the basic and the odbc drivers). Now I am trying to run `odbc_update_ini.sh` but none of the paths I have tried for the ODBCDM_Home argument seem to be correct. On `OSX` where I installed `unixodbc` with `brew` I was able to use `/usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.4/` to make things work correctly. But I cannot figure out the ubuntu/apt-get equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always change `odbc.ini` and `odbcinst.ini` manually. If you really want to use this `odbc_update_ini.sh` utility I would suggest to analyze its source code in order to check the path of the files it uses.

I won't be surprised if you need to set ODBCDM_Home to the root (`/`) directory.

Comment: "I always change odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini manually." Then, can you please explain how? What should I put in these files? This is not a solution...

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Xubuntu 20.04 and instant client from package instantclient-odbc-linux.x64-19.14.0.0.0dbru.zip) has `ODBCDM_HOME` value `/`:

```
sudo ./odbc_update_ini.sh /
```

There is a check in the script `odbc_update_ini.sh`. The script checks if a Driver Manager is installed by searching two files: `$ODBCDM_HOME/etc/odbc.ini` and `$ODBCDM_HOME/etc/odbcinst.ini`. Both of these files I found in: `/etc/odbc.ini` and `/etc/odbcinst.ini` so `ODBCDM_HOME` must be `/`.

So the value is not related to apt get, it is a matter of the script `odbc_update_ini.sh` which is part of the package of the Oracle ODBS client.

BTW: Reading that script was very useful, because it did not work for me from some reason. The script created file `/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_14/odbc.ini` but it was not able to move the file to `$HOME/odbc.ini` so I had to move the file manually.